# Could there theoretically exist a material so light, that it can levitate in the air just due to the in height decreasing air pressure?

Tags: pressure, air, bernoulli-equation, levitation

Airplanes can fly because the pressure on the top of the wing is lower than on the bottom. But the difference in pressure must be huge in order to lift an enire airplane. Also, the difference in air pressure between, let's say, Mount Everest and sea level is not neglectable, thus, air pressure is  decreasing the heigher you go.

> This is where I asked myself:
>  Can we theoretically build a material which is light enough or high enough (or both), that can levitate just due to the difference in pressure on the top vs. the bottom like an on an airplane wing.

*For example imagine you're holding a piece of paper horizontally, then air pressure on the top is slightly lower due to the decreasing air pressure and now just make the piece of paper as light as it needs to be to stay in the air like a wing on a flying airplane*

Is this theoretically possible or are there other effects or simplifications I overlooked?

Comment: Re, "Airplanes can fly because the pressure on the top of the wing is lower than on the bottom." That explanation has been making the rounds for almost as long as airplanes have been flying. Unfortunately, it is not true: https://www.grc.nasa.gov/www/k-12/airplane/wrong1.html

Comment: @SolomonSlow and at the same time, it is true. The pressure on the bottom of the wing *is* higher than on the top of the wing as a necessary condition for developing lift. It just has less to do with Bernoulli and more to do the with the wing, basically, pushing air out of the way.

Comment: @hobbs, Touché. You are absolutely right. I just _assumed_ that when somebody starts by talking about the pressure difference, they must be informed by the old trope. Whereas, if somebody starts by talking about the mass of the air and the wings beating it down, then they must be better informed.

Comment: People mentioned balloons and aerogels full of bubbles, But if you were thinking about a solid material you could expand your question. In order to be less dense than air the atoms should have a big average distance between them and still be bound together. Air molecules except for the biatomic binding are very far apart. In order to reduce the required distance you could use lithium and hydrogen atoms, but still they would have to be far apart. What could be the longest distance two atoms can have while sharing an electron? I don't know the answer, but I doubt it could be enough.

Comment: Last month's Scientific American had an article about how airplane wings work. There are multiple processes involved, and scientists aren't totally sure of the physics.

Comment: Interesting related question could be taking a known object and varying the pressure gradient in order to lift it...

Comment: @SolomonSlow Yeah, I can relate to that instinct.  Your trigger word should be _Bernoulli_ though, not pressure difference.  Pressure difference is just as accurate as looking at the momentum transfer with the air; it's usually when people try to _explain_ the pressure difference that it goes south.

Comment: @JMac Bernoulli itself is not the wrong answer, at least at speeds where compressibility is not an issue. Where Bernoulli-based explanations usually go wrong is in fallacious attempts to explain the origin of the differences in airspeed in the vicinity of an airfoil, such as the equal transit-time fallacy, which is simply wrong, and would not be sufficient even if it were correct.

Comment: @sdenham Yes, that's something I thought of too late after I made the comment.  Bernoulli is usually a good trigger word, but it's not always wrong, just the common wrong explanation applies it often.

Comment: @Barmar That's not quite true. We've known about the physics since the mid 1800s. The problem is the theory has no simple human-understandable explanation. The equations that explains movement in fluids (water, air etc.) is well-known. Unfortunately it calculates the movement and forces at a single point. To calculate the total flow you'd have to do the calculations over hundreds, thousands or millions of points in 2D or 3D space. It's a bit like trying to explain how to bake delicious cookies using quantum theory

Comment: @slebetman The article is [No One Can Explain Why Planes Stay In The Air](https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/no-one-can-explain-why-planes-stay-in-the-air/)

Comment: @Barmar That's not true either. The explanation is simple - when solving the Navier-Stokes equations for the airplane as a whole the pressure above the wings is lower than below the wings (also, the pressure behind the wings end up being lower than in front of the wings - we call this "drag"). The problem is not that there is no explanation. It is that there is no intuitive explanation. With Navier-Stokes asking "what shape of wings give good lift" is answered with "try many different designs and run simulations then compare" - useful for a computer but not very understandable to humans

Comment: @slebetman I'm not a physicist or aerospace engineer, I assume SciAm is not lying. The title may be an oversimplification, but the text goes into plenty of detail about what they don't really understand. The formulas obviously work since we can manufacture airfoils, but they don't really understand all the underlying physics.

Comment: @Barmar That's what I'm trying to get across - we do understand the "underlying" physics - it's driven by inertia and conservation of momentum (this gives rise to secondary effects like viscosity and pressure). But we understand it for a given point in space. What we don't have is an understanding of the bigger picture. Like I said - in theory quantum theory explains everything except things involving gravity. So in theory you can explain what makes a good cookie using quantum theory. In practice the human mind is unable to do all the calculations necessary to understand cookies at that level

Comment: @slebetman "There are two competing theories that illuminate the forces and factors of lift. Both are incomplete explanations. Aerodynamicists have recently tried to close the gaps in understanding. Still, no consensus exists."

Comment: @Barmar What pages like Nasa's is saying is that we know why things fly but can't put it into words to form a "simple" explanation. All simple explanations get something about flight wrong

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105465/discussion-between-barmar-and-slebetman).

Comment: [Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12767/179151) about the closing of this question.

Answer (score 52):

A hot air balloon, or a helium-filled balloon floats in air, so either might meet your criteria.

If you're looking for a solid material, perhaps a sphere of very sparse aerogel, with its outside surface sealed with a thin layer of plastic then evacuated, could come close to what you have in mind.  But whatever the "material" is, it would need to have a lower mass density than the ambient air.

Comment: The hot air balloon and the helium balloon are flying because hot air and helium are lighter than air, this is another effect. Also the material does not necessarily need to be lighter than air because anything that is lighter than air is levitating anyways. We don't use the effect of the difference in pressure here.

Comment: @J.Doe This is *not* another effect - buoyancy is precisely the force that you're talking about (a net imbalance in pressure above and below the object) and being less dense than air is precisely the criterion required such that the buoyant force overcomes gravity.

Comment: I feel the answer is incomplete without mentioning that this evacuated aerogel exists and is lighter than air. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel#Silica): "The lowest-density silica nanofoam weighs 1,000 g/m3,[19] which is the evacuated version of the record-aerogel of 1,900 g/m3.[20] The density of air is 1,200 g/m3 (at 20 °C and 1 atm).[21] As of 2013, aerographene had a lower density at 160 g/m3, or 13% the density of air at room temperature.[22]"

Comment: @JollyJoker Ok, so the aerogel is less dense than air. But I couldn't find anything about the mechanical strength of aerogel. Would the wrapped and evacuated version be strong enough to withstand atmospheric pressure, or would it just collapse under the pressure of the surrounding air?

Comment: @J.Doe _"Also the material does not necessarily need to be lighter than air because anything that is lighter than air is levitating anyways."_ Being lighter than air is the _only_ way in which something can levitate (based on its atmospheric environment and not some additional outside force such as a magnet or wind cannon - which would similarly invalidate the question). If you define levitation as hanging _still_ in the air instead of ascending, then the object needs the exact same density as the air surrounding it.

Comment: @J.Murray Isn't buoyancy the effect of something being lighter than the water/air/…, so the water streams below the objects and that creates an upwards force? OP is asking about using the already existing pressure difference, not creating a new one by letting the air/… flow downwards. Or am I misunderstanding something here? In that case, can you (or someone) please explain it differently?

Comment: @FabianRöling No, see [here](https://physics.info/buoyancy/summary.shtml)

Comment: @FabianRöling there is (we can assume) already fluid on *all* sides of the object. It doesn't need to fall down to fill in an "empty" space. So what creates an upward force on the object? The fact that there is fluid pressure on all sides of the object, but the pressure on the bottom of the object is greater than the pressure on the top (because of the pressure gradient in the fluid).

Comment: @JMurray I think this question could really use a good answer clearly explaining why this is exactly the same thing as buoyancy. None of the current answers address that directly.

Comment: The question is asking about whether a constant density object can be buoyant because the air at its top is lower density than the air at its bottom. So buoyancy is relevant, but not most of the story as the effect is caused by the declining density of air with height. So you are basically not answering the question but describing the simpler properties of a balloon.

Comment: @matt_black The question is not about density, which it never mentions.

Comment: @sdenham the question says "...the difference in pressure on the top vs. the bottom" implying something more complex than simple buoyancy. hence my assumptions.

Comment: @matt_black I do not see that implication, and no-one else here seems to, either. The question is written clearly and makes sense as it stands. If you think the question's author meant something else, you should have asked for clarification in the comments. It is not clear to me why you or anyone else might think there is a density issue here, unless one misunderstands the physics of buoyancy.

Comment: @matt_black The question was only specifically asking about pressure.  It's not even clear if OP recognized the difference in how air pressure varies in air as compared to something near incompressible like water.  I think it's good to mention that it varies differently and that can be exploited, but to me it seemed like OP was misunderstanding buoyancy.

Answer (score 6):

Is this theoretically possible with only one single material? Yes. Any object occupying a volume of gas (or liquid, or solid) has a slightly higher pressure underneath it than the pressure on top of it (while sitting still) due to the pressure decreasing with height. If it is less dense than the air it occupies (combined weight of both its outside envelope and the mass inside), then the slightly differential air pressure will cause it to rise.  It will continue to rise until the differential air pressure matches the weight of the object.

A balloon's weight, combined with lighter than air gas inside achieves this. The helium in a balloon doesn't push on the top inner side of the balloon to make it go up. It is the stronger outside pressure on the bottom of the balloon than is on the top that makes it rise. The helium has enough pressure to maintain the envelope of the balloon, but low enough mass so that the entire weight of the balloon is less than the amount of air that occupies the same volume of the balloon.  Same idea for things that float on a liquid (the differential pressure is larger, allowing large ships made from metal).

It is not just like an airplane wing. Airplane wings accelerate the airflow downward  (with a bit of Bernoulli as well), like a water skier, and the wing needs to be moving through the air.

> Is this theoretically possible or are there other effects or
>   simplifications I overlooked?

Theoretically, two configurations I can think of:

- A single material heavier than air, but with a vacuum inside, light enough to be less dense overall, but strong enough to not only prevent air from leaking inside, but prevent the air from crushing it as well; or
- As you alluded to, a solid whose density is less than that of air.

Comment: It is not just theoretically possible, it is actually how buoyancy works. You don't seem to understand that. Everything that floats works in that way.

Comment: "It is the stronger **external** pressure on the bottom of the balloon than is on the top that makes it rise."

Comment: Again, the question isn't asking whether lighter than air flight is possible. It is asking whether it is possible *purely because air density varies with height* which is not how normal buoyancy works.

Comment: @matt_black The question does not mention density at all! And buoyancy (normal buoyancy - the only sort there is) works the same way regardless of whether the fluid is constant-density or not, as a consequence of a difference in *pressure*.

Comment: @sdenham I was, perhaps falsely, assuming the OP wasn't talking about the explanation for normal buoyancy but was asking whether the difference in pressure with height would be enough to cause buoyancy. Perhaps I overinterpreted it.

Comment: @matt_black Well, yes, the question's author was asking, very clearly, "whether the difference in pressure with height would be enough to cause buoyancy", and the answer is "that is exactly what buoyancy is." It is not clear to me why you might think varying density with height has anything to do with what was asked.

Comment: Updated with some of the comments.

Answer (score 4):

Congratulations! You have figured out the basis of [Archimedes' principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedes%27_principle). The article linked here gives a satisfactory explanation, though the main point can be made simply:

Consider a vertically-oriented cylinder within the fluid. The difference in pressure between the top and bottom of that cylinder is due to the weight of the fluid within it, and is just that weight *divided* by its cross-sectional area. Substitute a solid body of the same dimensions, and the difference in the force exerted by the fluid on the top and the bottom of that body -- the upthrust on it -- is the difference in pressure *multiplied* by the cross-sectional area. But that is just the weight of the fluid that formerly occupied the space taken by that body, and has now been displaced by it.

Considering any irregularly-shaped object as a bundle of thin cylinders, each buoyed by the fluid it displaces, it is clear that shape does not matter, only volume. The upthrust is greater than the body's weight if the body weighs less than the fluid it displaces, and as they are the same volumes, this is just when the body is less dense than the fluid.

The answer to your question, therefore, is that anything of a density equal to or less than than air will float in air, and balloons containing hydrogen or helium are the most common examples. Other answers have suggested vacuum aerogels, but an aerogel containing hydrogen or helium at atmospheric pressure is a more straightforward candidate, as it does not require the gel to have any great strength. For example, the lightest [evacuated aerogel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerogel#Silica) achieved so far has a density of 1000 $g/m^3$, and room temperature and pressure hydrogen has a density of 83.2 $g/m^3$, giving a density for the gel, when infused with hydrogen, of no more than 1083.2 $g/m^3$, less that the density of air in the same conditions - 1200 $g/m^3$ (the surface of the aerogel would have to be sealed with a membrane, but its contribution to the density would decrease with increasing volume, by the familiar surface area / volume scaling.)

More radically, this [aerographene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aerographene) has an evacuated density of only 160 $g/m^3$.

Comment: Not answering the question! Buoyancy in a constant density fluid doesn't depend on the different density of the fluid at different heights, just on whether or not the suspended object is of a lower density.

Comment: @matt_black Firstly, the last paragraph answers the question. Secondly, where do you see any reference to different densities of the fluid at different heights?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to baloons is a spheric shell, with vacuum inside, with a thickness and material strength designed to resist to atmospheric pressure. The force upwards is the equivalent to the weight of air. And its weight is proportional to the surface and thickness. For a thin shell:

$$F_\text{up} = \mu_\text{air} g (4/3)\pi r^3$$
$$\text{weight} = \mu_\text{shell} g 4\pi r^2 \cdot \text{thickness}$$

In order to fluctuate $F_\text{up} \ge \text{weight} \Rightarrow \mu_\text{air}/\mu_\text{shell} \ge 3\cdot\text{thickness}/r$

For a shell made from steel ($\mu = 7850\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$) with $10\ \mathrm{mm}$ of thickness, and for $\mu_\text{air} = 1.2\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}$

$$r_\text{min}= \frac{7850\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}}{1.2\ \mathrm{kg/m^3}} \times 3 \times 0.010\ \mathrm m = 196\ \mathrm m $$

If it could resist to the pressure of $1\ \mathrm{kg/cm^2}$ without collapsing is another question.

Comment: Please note that descriptive terms or names of quantities shall not be arranged in the form of an equation.

Comment: @Loong, Your way is more clear, but I've never heard of any such law. The symbols we use, like *F* for force or *a* for acceleration are just shorthand for the names.

Comment: @ThePhoton No. Quantity symbols such as $F$ and unit symbols such as $\mathrm N$ are mathematical entities and not abbreviations. Quantity names and unit names are not mathematical entities. That’s why such names shall not be arranged in the form of an equation (e.g. write “$\mathrm{kg\cdot m^2}$” or “kilogram metre squared”, not “$\text{kilogram}\cdot\text{metre}^2$”). Furthermore, symbols and names shall not be mixed (e.g. write “$\mathrm{g/mol}$” or “gram per mole”, neither “$\mathrm{g}/\text{mole}$”, “g per mole”, “$\text{gram}/\mathrm{mol}$”, nor “gram per mol”).

Comment: @Loong, when you say "shall not" it sounds like you think there's some legal authority or word of God that created this rule. What authority is making this absolute rule that you're expressing here?

Answer (score 1):

You're asking about air, I think, but if you mean gasses in general, then aerogels are a kind of substance that can float on xenon.  Wikipedia and YouTube have lots of information.

Comment: Could it float in the middle of a gravitationally caused density gradient of Xenon (or another gas)?

Comment: Simply put, "yes".

Answer (score 0):

It's a vacuum balloon. A sphere of implausibly strong material, with a vacuum  inside. It will rise until the weight of the air it is displacing equals the weight of that implausibly strong sphere. And in Science Fiction, it can stay aloft indefinitely and adjust its altitude by means of a small vacuum pump, batteries, solar panels and a leak valve ....

For a proof of concept (were one needed) that might actually work up to a few thousand metres altitude, I'd look for the strongest aerogel I could find, wrap it in a thin tough plastic membrane, and suck the air out using a vacuum pump. *If* the aerogel did not collapse under the pressure, you may have your vacuum balloon.

In the real world we fill a membrane with helium or hydrogen, and this has no need for implausibly strong materials. They can rise until they go pop as the gas inside expands. Google has a "loon" project for balloons which regulate their altitude so they don't pop, creating high-altitude non-satellites to bring broadband and phone services to truly remote areas.

Comment: Have you done basic calculations as to pressure, thickness of gel, etc.?  I have a feeling it would work fine but I'm too tired

Comment: No. Not even sure how I would. It would mean modelling a huge sparsely connected set of semi-random nodes in three dimensions, and knowing a lot about the strength distribution of the connections. You'd need a big computer. My instincts tell me that local collapses would at least initially lead to stress relief and that the network would be self-strengthening, up to the point of catastrophic failure. An experimental test would be very much easier!

Comment: I'm not talking modelling at the atom level.  There are videos showing 2g of aerogel holding up a 2kg brick.  Sea level air pressure is 1.03kg per sq cm, so would need 1g aerogel per sq cm.  I don't know what thickness of gel would give you 1g at 1cmx1cm, but knowing that just set weight(x) = buoyancy(x), where x is the centimeters, and solve for x.  weight would be a sphere of x radius times aerogel density, minus sphere of x-thickness radius times aerogel density for the hollow center.  You might end up with basically a solid balloon that would crumple on pretty much any impact...